# Why can't I add a Wifi network in Windows 10?

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10

I have a brand new computer I just assembled and installed Windows 10 on it. I cannot reach my ethernet cable to plug into it across the room, but I cannot use wifi on it either. If I go to "Network & Internet" there is no "Wifi" option at all! I have seen references online to problems upgrading from windows 8 but this is brand new machine!

Comment: Well my first thought is, because you say you assembled it, I'm pretty sure you are talking about a desktop machine, rather than a laptop. Desktop computers don't necessarily have a built in wi-fi. Do you know if the computer has any wifi capabilities? Some motherboards have integrated wi-fi... If this one doesn't´, you have to get a separate usb wi-fi adapter or a PCI-E wi-fi card.

Comment: Does this new computer have wifi hardware? Not all do.

Comment: You should at least buy a longer Ethernet cable for when you need a wired connection. You can get cables up to 100m.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should check whether your computer has a wireless network interface card or not. If the answer is yes, then you should pay attention on the wireless network interface card driver. To do this, follow the step below:

Step 1:

<kbd>windows</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and click network connection

Step2:

check whether you have  the "WLAN" of "WIFI" , then you could right click it and choose "connect". If not, you should install the lastest network interface card driver from your provider.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your's brand new system contains the Wi-Fi, you said that you've assembled have you inserted any add-on card for Wi-Fi if you've installed it what about the driver package for it.If you have a added the Wi-Fi card check it in Device Manager->Network Adapters it will show your device or else as Unknown Device.